# JavaScript Prompt command is not working in HTML

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a curriculum course which requires to me a make program that asks students how many hours a day they study, however I can't get the prompt command to work in these lines of JavaScript:

```
<html>
<body>
<script>

var studiedhours = prompt("How many hours do you study a day?");

if (studiedhours <= 0) { alert{"Sorry, you must enter a number between 0 and 24"}
}
    else if (studiedhours >= 5) {
    alert("Well Done! \n Keep it up!")
}
    else if (studiedhours >= 24) {
    alert("Sorry, there is only 24 hours in a day, you entered an invalid number")
}
else {
    alert("You should study more!")
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What is stopping the prompt command from working?

Comment: `alert{"Sorry, you must enter a number between 0 and 24"}` should be `alert("Sorry, you must enter a number between 0 and 24")`

Comment: first alert should be `alert()` not `alert{}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a syntax error in your code.

Use parenthesis, instead curly brace in this line.

```
 alert{"Sorry, you must enter a number between 0 and 24"}
```

to

```
 alert("Sorry, you must enter a number between 0 and 24")
```

hope this will help.

Comment: That worked thanks! I didn't even notice that I had used curly brackets there.